# How to delete user when delete profile?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(255),nullable=False,unique=True)
    profile= db.relationship('Profile',backref='user',uselist=False,passive_deletes=True
        ,lazy=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'User({self.id})'

class Profile(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'profiles'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('users.id',ondelete='CASCADE'),unique=True)
```

> 1)When delete parent it's worked.

2)db.session.delete(profile) -> db.session.commit() -> User not deleted??

Comment: is `on_delete=models.CASCADE` not working?

Comment: no when delete child.

Comment: I think you should configure your User and Parent to have an one-to-one relationship: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-one